# Cannot find -ly error

Tags: linux, yacc, lex

I am trying to run a lexx and yacc program and I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Plz tell me which libraries am I supposed to add?

Comment: Why are you using `-ly`? Are you trying to link against a library called `liby`? Are you sure that library exists?

Comment: I'm sure the error is *not* given by `lex` (actually you may want to use `flex`) and `yacc` (actually consider `bison`), but by the `gcc` compiler during the linking phase. So please show your real `gcc` command....

Answer (score 2):

Could you find `liby.a` in `/lib` dir? If you don't have the file, you can use `apt-file liby.a` to find the package which includes it. In my case, `apt install libbison-dev` works.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the problem is that you're using a version of yacc other than the old AT&T yacc which doesn't come with liby (the `-ly` you have).  So you need to remove the `-ly` option from your command line, and provide your own implementations of `main` and `yyerror`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of yacc and lex have the "-ly" parametr? 
I used this command in my university:

gcc gram.c gram.h sem.c -ly -ll 
or
cc gram.c gram.h sem.c -ly -ll

And works!  But on my home komputer doesn't work..

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but rather a comment or possibly a new question. SO is not a discussion forum, so answers should be answers. If you feel, you can raise a new question, referring to this question. Thanks!