# Fix: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: gcc, yacc, lex

I can't compile yacc i lex:

```
$ cc gramatyka.c gramatyka.h semantyka.c -ly -ll
```

output error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find -ly error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877798/cannot-find-ly-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are missing the `-L path/to/dir/with/liby` in your `LDFLAGS` (in case liby is in the same folder, just prepend `-L.` before `-ly`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because compiler is not able to link this library. Add the complete path using "-L" option if you are not sure about default location of this library.